# Issue with Configuring Self Registration in Flask-AppBuilder and Enabling Less Secure Apps in Google

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

I'm trying to configure self-registration functionality in Flask-AppBuilder, but I'm facing a problem with enabling the Less Secure Apps setting in Google. As of now, Google no longer supports enabling Less Secure Apps, which is causing issues with sending emails for user registration.

When attempting to register a new user, I encounter the following error message:
ERROR: flask_appbuilder.security.registerviews:Send email exception: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d5-20020a170902cec500b001b54d064a4bsm857584plg.259 - gsmtp')

I understand that the error is due to Google's security measures, but I'm wondering if there is an alternative approach to handle user registration without relying on Less Secure Apps.

Is there a way to configure Flask-AppBuilder to use a different SMTP server or another method to send registration confirmation emails? I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to overcome this issue.

Thank you in advance!